# PHPMailer: Classname not found when trying to use Gmail's SMTP

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I've been trying to get PHPMailer to work for about a week now. At first I did not use SMTP, but I had to change this because of PHP permissions.

Since the e-mail address that's being used seems to be bought through Gmail (it has a different domain, not @gmail.com) I figured it was best to use the Gmail SMTP service of Google. (Which is explained here https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2)

Because of inexperience and a lack of any way to approach my host via commandline, I got all the necessary packages with a locally installed version of composer and copied all dependencies through FTP to my host. My current folder structure is now like this:

```
/phpmailer
/phpmailer/extras/
/phpmailer/language/
/phpmailer/vendor/
/phpmailer/vendor/composer/
/phpmailer/vendor/eloquent/
/phpmailer/vendor/guzzlehttp/
/phpmailer/vendor/league/
/phpmailer/vendor/paragonie/
/phpmailer/vendor/phpmailer/
/phpmailer/vendor/psr/
/phpmailer/vendor/autoload.php
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

Fatal error: Class 'League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google' not found in /domain/phpmailer/class.phpmaileroauthgoogle.php on line 55

It looks as if it is missing an include or require somewhere, so I tried adding require('vendor/autoload.php'); in my PHP that handles the form that should start the mailing process, but it does not seem to solve anything. And I also do not expect that adding something like that to files in /phpmailer/ should be necessary.

The rest of the log that I get returned looks like this:

2017-03-26 10:23:52 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP e16sm10314377wra.62 - gsmtp 2017-03-26 10:23:52  CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.domain.com 2017-03-26 10:23:53   SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2a0b:7280:100:0:447:56ff:fe00:207b] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 2017-03-26 10:23:53 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 2017-03-26 10:23:53  SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS 2017-03-26 10:23:53  CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.domain.com 2017-03-26 10:23:53   SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2a0b:7280:100:0:447:56ff:fe00:207b] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8

It does not really seem to be a problem with authentication.

This is what's in composer.json:

```
{
"name": "phpmailer/phpmailer",
"type": "library",
"description": "PHPMailer is a full-featured email creation and transfer class for PHP",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Marcus Bointon",
        "email": "phpmailer@synchromedia.co.uk"
    },
    {
        "name": "Jim Jagielski",
        "email": "jimjag@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "Andy Prevost",
        "email": "codeworxtech@users.sourceforge.net"
    },
    {
        "name": "Brent R. Matzelle"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.0.0",
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^5.2",
    "league/oauth2-client": "^2.2",
    "league/oauth2-google": "^2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "doctrine/annotations": "1.2.*",
    "jms/serializer": "0.16.*",
    "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "2.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.8.*",
    "symfony/debug": "2.8.*",
    "symfony/filesystem": "2.8.*",
    "symfony/translation": "2.8.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "2.8.*",
    "zendframework/zend-cache": "2.5.1",
    "zendframework/zend-config": "2.5.1",
    "zendframework/zend-eventmanager": "2.5.1",
    "zendframework/zend-filter": "2.5.1",
    "zendframework/zend-i18n": "2.5.1",
    "zendframework/zend-json": "2.5.1",
    "zendframework/zend-math": "2.5.1",
    "zendframework/zend-serializer": "2.5.*",
    "zendframework/zend-servicemanager": "2.5.*",
    "zendframework/zend-stdlib": "2.5.1"
},
"suggest": {
    "league/oauth2-google": "Needed for Google XOAUTH2 authentication"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "class.phpmailer.php",
        "class.phpmaileroauth.php",
        "class.phpmaileroauthgoogle.php",
        "class.smtp.php",
        "class.pop3.php",
        "extras/EasyPeasyICS.php",
        "extras/ntlm_sasl_client.php"
    ]
},
"license": "LGPL-2.1"
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you post the content of your composer json file? since it controls which modules and classes are added to your php's classpath.

Comment: Hi, I added the contents of composer.json in my initial post

Comment: I think your issue is related to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69487739/5810125

Answer (score 0):

(Edit: Apologies, I didn't see that you'd already added the dependency to your composer.json)

That extra dependency should really be in your own apps's `composer.json` (not PHPMailer's), because you should never need to edit packages loaded via composer. You probably just need to run `composer update` (not just `composer install`). Otherwise it will only load the packages in the most recent `composer.lock` file, not extra ones that you have added.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply. I did run `composer update` and transferred the resulted updates to my host, but it still says `Fatal error: Class 'League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google' not found in /phpmailer/class.phpmaileroauthgoogle.php on line 55`. 
What dependency are you referring to that should be in my own app's json-file? As far as I know, I only have one `composer.json`, and that's situated in /phpmailer/.

Comment: If I update composer, I do get a `composer.json` that has much less content. It only contains "require: { ... } "