# PHPMailer seems to not install correctly: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer

Tags: phpmailer

I am getting the error above when I run my code. Following the instructions on the PHPMAiler Github page, I added  "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0" to my composer.json but PHPMailer seems not to load.

I tried using $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(true) instead of $Mail = new PHPMailer(true).  I went to the Composer IRC channel to see if my problem was with Composer.  I have also tried using the full path in the require 'vendor/autoload.php'; statement.

```
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';


//other code...

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

I expect PHPMailer to run.  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Did you run `composer install`? Is the package present in `vendor/phpmailer`?

Comment: I did not run install.  I used the instructions on this page. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer .  there is  a phpmailer directory under vendor and it has sub-directories and files.  Am I looking for one particular one.

Comment: Using `composer require` also installs the package, but there’s no harm in running `install` again, so give it another go to ensure the autoloader gets regenerated.

Comment: running composer require again did it.  I do not know why.  That worked on staging but I am having the same problem on production and no number of resinstalls is fixing it.  Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

When I had difficulty running PHPMailer on my local XAMPP server and the composer, I ended up installing the file manually by loading it into my directory

htdocs
-index.php
-Other_Program_to_run_with_PHPMailer.php
-folder(PHPMailer)

```
    <?php

    $messege=""

    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'insert Username';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'insert Password';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom('insert username', 'Information');
    $mail->addAddress('who it is being sent to', 'PHP Management');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addReplyTo('who they can reply to', 'PHP Management');

    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = ;
    $mail->Body    = $message;

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'The following Message has been sent';

        echo $message;
    }

?>
```

From there I have been copy and pasting onto my server and it works out pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

**Scott**

**Your problem may be solved if you would have read the documentations. Use the below code at first.**

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

just download the phpMailer Class from that GIT repo  link

```
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
```

and extract/copy three files  PHPMailer.php, Extension.php and SMTP.php files put them in a folder name : (PHPMailer) like in the image bellow :-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6DXW.png

and just add these lines of code at the top of your file

```
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
//  require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require('PHPMailer/Exception.php');
require('PHPMailer/SMTP.php');
require('PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php');
```